# Looping multidimensional array and checking if then in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, conditional-statements

I have this

```
<?php

//array[x][y] right?
$condition = array
(
array("cat","meow"),
array("cow","moo"),
array("dog","bark"),
);

//Do I need two For loops to be able to go through each array values?

if($condition==array[x]){
    echo array[y];
}
?>
```

I am trying to loop through a multidimensional array and print the array if the condition is right. I hope my question is not vague enough. But I am a bit stuck and I don't know how to loop through them properly. I would prefer any help or pointing me in the right direction. Thank you.

Comment: You might want to look at using `foreach` instead - `foreach($condition as $subarray)` or if using an associative array and wanting keys and values `foreach($condition as $key=>$value)`

Comment: Not sure what you mean by *if the condition is right* - what would `$condition` contain? It is `cat` for example?

Comment: @NigelRen didn't even notice the "condition" part. Good point what is this condition? What is the expected input and output

Answer (score 0):

In this case you don't need two loops, you can use implode.
But generally, yes you would need two loops.

```
$condition = array
(
array("cat","meow"),
array("cow","moo"),
array("dog","bark"),
);

foreach($condition as $cond){
    echo implode(" says ", $cond) . "\n";
}

//cat says meow
//cow says moo
//dog says bark
```

Conventional method is to loop twice as you say.

```
foreach($condition as $cond){
    foreach($cond as $item){
        echo $item ." ";
    }
}
```

Now that I think about it you could also do:

```
foreach($condition as $cond){
    echo $cond[0] . " says " . $cond[1] . "\n"; 
}
```

And this will give the same result as the first example.

Answer (score 0):

**If I don't misunderstood you question**, then you can use a single `foreach()` loop to check condition with your array element value.

```
<?php
$array = array
    (
    array("cat","meow"),
    array("cow","moo"),
    array("dog","bark"),
);
//you can use single foreach() loop to iterate your $array
$condition = 'cat'; //demo condition
print_r($array);
foreach($array as $k=>$v){
    if($condition == $v[0]){
        echo $v[1];
    }
}
?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/k7mh0